# How can I create generated/formula text in word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I commonly work on a specific template that a heading thats formatted like this;

```
[Section Name] -- 10 min -- 0:00 to 0:10
[Section Name 2] -- 15 min -- 0:10 to 0:25
and so on...
```

I would like the part after the second '--' to be auto generated. As in, it will determine how long the sections before it have taken. And then use that to put in a start and a finish. (Like the power of an excel formula referencing previous cells.)

The text should be in line with the heading and formatted the same way.

Also at the end, I would like it to say- `Total time: 160 min`

I am thinking I need to use VBA to do this, but I'm not sure where to start. I would've though this would be a common problem/want with Microsoft Word, but I can't find anyone asking a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following vba script searches for the minutes (after the first "--") in each paragraph formatted by the style "yourStyle". Then it adds from - to to the end of each line and adds the total duration in minutes to the end of the document.

```
Sub InsertText()

Dim Parag As Paragraph
Dim t0 As Double
t0 = TimeValue("0:00:00")

For Each Parag In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    With Parag.Range
        If .Style = "yourStyle" Then
            minutes = TimeValue("00:" + Split(Right(.Text, Len(.Text) - InStr(.Text, "--") - 2))(0) + ":00")
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            .Move wdCharacter, -1
            .InsertAfter (" -- " + Format(t0, "h:nn") + " to " + Format(t0 + minutes, "h:nn"))
            t0 = t0 + minutes
        End If
    End With
Next

Selection.EndKey wdStory, wdExtend
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText (Format(t0, "n") + " minutes")

End Sub
```